# Text in a UILabel isn't wrapping

Tags: ios

I'm displaying 2 or three lines of text in a UILabel however the text is getting truncated rather than wrapping.

Within IB Line Breaks is set to Word Wrap and the height of the label is easily plenty to accommodate the lines of text.

I'm doing exactly the same thing as this in other labels in other views and they do wrap, I can't see any reason or anything different why this one won't wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `numberOfLines` for the `UILabel` to either `0` or whatever number of lines you want it to be. Setting it to `0` will automatically choose the number of lines based on the length of the text. The default is `1`.

Edit: I just checked and in IB, the property is just called `Lines`.